# How to generate oauth token for webapi without using client id and client secret

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have deployed one webapi into azure. After that I have register my API into Azure AD.

I got my API client-id and client-secret, now i just want to test my API not like 
3rd application will access it so what will be recourse id in this case.

I have used oauth for authentication into that webapi.

I want to test that webapi so into POSTMAN i used this url to generate oauth token

which i will pass as header `Authentication` bearer token.

step 1 - 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{OAuth_Tenant}}/oauth2/token

in header -

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:{{client_id}}           // i have my API client-id
client_secret:{{client_secret}}   // i have my API client-secret
resource:{{resource}}             // i have my API client-id
```

when i generate token using above values and send that bearer token it fail error unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an app in Azure Active Directory to acquire access tokens.

Register an app there, and you can find the client id/application id there.
Then you can create a key for the app, that's your client secret.
Finally the resource should be the client id or app id URI for your API's app registration in Azure AD.

To implement this according to best practices, you'll also want to look into defining app permissions for your API, so you can then assign privileges to apps to call your API.

Comment: Yes I have register my API into Azure AD and I have got my client-id and client-secret of API but what will be resource in this case because i want to access or test my API only not like from 3rd app i'm accessing API.

Comment: Hmm, you can try using your API client id as the resource. Technically postman is a 3rd party app calling your API though.

Comment: i tried to generate token by passing 
client-id = my API client Id
client-secret = my API client secret
resource = my API client id
I got bearer token using this url - https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{OAuth_Tenant}}/oauth2/token

but when I call my webapi - https://mydemo.azurewebsites.net/getorders 
and bearer token it still giving 401 unauthorized

Comment: Can you check the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms and see what for example the audience (aud) is? Does it match the valid audience in your API?

Comment: `aud` and `appid` is having same id value i.e nothing but my API appID.

Comment: @Neo You and juunas seem to be on the right track with registering the app first and checking audience for incoming token, which also looks fine based on your last comment.. one thing that isn't clear (maybe only to me) is how did you even implement Azure AD based authentication for your API without registering any app first (I say this looking at history of your question edits where you did not have an app registration and were looking for clientid/secret).. May be something is missing in your API configuration.. if possible add your api's startup authentication related code to question.